# How to display "In two columns with multiple rows having title and labels in bootstrap display

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to display an form seperated by two columns having multiple rows and few rows grouped with an header using Bootstrap.
Please help me how to display ,the below i tried where during Zoomin and Zoom-out the columns are shrinked and aligned like row.

Eg: When i zoom-out to 200%, The Serial Specification List input box aligned under the label and image goes below.
I would like to have them look the same during Zoomin or out.

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js">    </script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
   </script>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-6" >
        <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg" style="width:103%;background:pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">Fruits List   </h5>
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
            <label for="colFormLabelSm"  style="width:40%;" >Serial Specifiction ID</label>
            <div>
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
        </div>
    <a href="javascript:UserID('ID')"><img style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom:5px; "  src="./help.png" class="img-rounded" alt="" width="25" height="20"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row"style="margin-left: auto">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;"  >Name</label>
        <div >
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row"style="margin-left: auto">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;" >Alias</label>
        <div >
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
        </div>
      </div>

 <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
      <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg bg-warning" style="width:100%;background:pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">DESCRIPTION</h5>
      
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>              
    </div>       
      <div class="col-sm-6" >
      <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg"style="width:100%;background:pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">Sub Category</h5>
          <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
          <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;">Classification</label>   
    <div >
   <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:326%;height:24px">
    <option>1</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
    <label for="colFormLabelSm"  style="width:40%;">No of orders</label>
    <div >
      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto;display:block ruby">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm"  style="width:40%;">Ordered by</label>
        <div class="">
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
        </div>
      </div>
         <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
              <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg" style="width:100%;background: pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">CONTACTS</h5>
              </div>    
       <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 5px;display:block ruby">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;">Ordered Contact Name</label>   
          <div >
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:326%;height:24px">
            <option>1</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
              <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg" style="width:100%;background:pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">Customer Specific Details
            </h5>
            </div>        
       <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 5px;display:block ruby">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:86%;">Existing Customer</label>   
          <div >
       <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:326%;height:24px">
        <option>YES</option>
           <option>NO</option>
         </select>
        </div>
      </div>        
    </div>
  </div>
            
        </div>
      </form>

      </html>
    </div>
```

Please guide me how to resolve this.

Comment: can you share the image of your `output` it will be really great! What I understand is that you want two column which you already did but input field  `width` is not working properly?

Comment: @FareedKhan: Have attached the link where Im facing currently zooming issue. When i zoom the alignment changes . Please help me how can i resolve this

Comment: @FareedKhan or Team: Please be kind to help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your `html` for just specific `input` tag which contain `image` in line, only change you will see is that your `input` field will have width `100%`.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg" style="width:103%;background:pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">Fruits List </h5>

  <!-- My code start -->
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <label class="pr-3" for="colFormLabelSm">Serial Specifiction ID</label>
        </div>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="" style="height:24px">
        <span id="basic-addon1">
            <a href="javascript:UserID('ID')"><img style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom:5px;" src="https://cdncontribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/GG-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" class="img-rounded" alt="" width="25" height="20" /></a>
          </span>
      </div>
<!-- My code end here -->


      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;">Name</label>
        <div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;">Alias</label>
        <div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
        <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg bg-warning" style="width:100%;background:pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">DESCRIPTION</h5>

        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg" style="width:100%;background:pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">Sub Category</h5>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;">Classification</label>
        <div>
          <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:326%;height:24px">
            <option>1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;">No of orders</label>
        <div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto;display:block ruby">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;">Ordered by</label>
        <div class="">
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="" style="width:103%;height:24px">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
        <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg" style="width:100%;background: pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">CONTACTS</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 5px;display:block ruby">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:40%;">Ordered Contact Name</label>
        <div>
          <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:326%;height:24px">
            <option>1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: auto">
        <h5 class="card-title col-form-label-lg" style="width:100%;background:pink; display: display;padding-left:10px;font-weight: bold">Customer Specific Details
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 5px;display:block ruby">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" style="width:86%;">Existing Customer</label>
        <div>
          <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:326%;height:24px">
            <option>YES</option>
            <option>NO</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```